# importing pygame on python3 on virtualenv cause ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, importerror

I have python3.3.1 on ubuntu lucid,which I invoke thru virtualenvwrapper ' .I wanted to learn pygame,so I used pip to install it.Before that I installed the sdl and smpeg dev libraries

```
me@ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
...
me@ubuntu: sudo apt-get install  libsmpeg-dev
...

me@ubuntu: workon envpy331
(envpy331)me@ubuntu:~$ pip install pygame

    Downloading pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz (2.1MB): 2.1MB downloaded
    Running setup.py egg_info for package pygame    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...

    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.14
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    SMPEG   : found 0.4.5
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
 ....
   Continuing With "setup.py"  

   Successfully installed pygame
   Cleaning up...
```

Then I tried to import pygame and this caused an import error

```
(envpy331)me@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 19 2013, 11:41:37) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux

>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/envpy331/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: /home/me/.virtualenvs/envpy331/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-33m.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr
```

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has not been entirely ported to Python 3, only some of the modules. If you use Python 2.7 everything should work. I recently had the same problem. Some suggested using individual modules of Pygame with Python 3 but this may be tricky to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old question but since I spent some time on the problem, this is the easiest way to install `pygame` for `python3.4` in its own virtual environment:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev virtualenvwrapper
echo "export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs" >> ~/.bashrc
echo ". /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

The above you do once. The following you repeat for each new environment:

```
mkvirtualenv -a ~/your/project/path -p /usr/bin/python3.4 your_project_name
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

This should download and compile the right `pygame` version (with bunch of warnings, yet working). Tested on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 and 14.10.

Each time you start working on a given project or wish to switch between projects:

```
workon your_project_name
```

The project name will appear in the prompt. And when you want to finish and go back to your system-wide environment:

```
deactivate
```